# How to create Android swipable Card View

Tags: android

How to create a swipable card view in android application using fragments.
In my application swipable view will shown unfortunately stopped error when swiping backward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some open source libraries in your project.

[SwipeCards](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards)
[Swipeable cards: Tinder-like cards library for Android](https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards)

Comment: Thanks cw fei, your link will support more features on my application

Comment: @sudharsan if it solve your issue, please mark as answer, thanks :)